# getting exception System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjectHandle while using XMLWorkerHelper in asp.netcore 2.0 with Itextsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to use ItextSharp to generate pdf but I am getting a exception on

```
XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr);

MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjectHandle System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.String, System.String)'.
```

What am I missing?

```
string data = await GetHtml(model.Review.PublishUrl);
                    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        StringReader sr = new StringReader(data);
                        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
                        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream);
                        pdfDoc.Open();

                        XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr);
                        pdfDoc.Close();
                        return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/pdf", "Grid.pdf");
                    }
```

Comment: i am with the same problem. What did you do?

Answer (score 1):

ITextSharp is not supported by **.Net core** or **.Net Standards**. I recommend using [Itext7](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet) which supports **.Net Standard 1.6** .